# Apex Data loader - Error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SW T libraries on 64-bit JVM

Tags: data-loader, java

I am trying  to run apex data loader downloaded and installed from my SalesForce account. But when I try to run the jar from command prompt with this command

```
java -jar dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.<init>(LoaderWindow.java:83)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:207)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:45)
```

I am not even running from eclipse , but why I see below line in the exception ??

```
 at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:263)
```

Mine is 64 bit Windows 8 OS. How to run it ?

Comment: Did the shortcut solution work for you?

Comment: Sorry it didn't ! I have set the path to 32 bit JRE came along with the data loader and run it using `java -jar dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set the path to 32 bit JRE came along with the data loader and run it using java -jar dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar. It worked!

Answer (score 3):

I have DataLoader running on 64bit Windows 8.

The best way to do this is

1. create a shortcut to the jar file (right click on it in Windows explorer and select 'create shortcut')
2. Then change the properties of the shortcut so the working directory is a valid directory your user can write to.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a 64 bit version of Java installed

One solution to this is to add the "-d32" argument to force the JRE into 32 bit mode.

```
java -jar -d32 dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar
```

Or you could install a 32 bit version of Java.

Comment: Or running it from a shortcut works for me, where I don't have 32 bit version of Java installed and the -d32 argument also doesn't work.